# HTML5 Geolocator max calls for respective browser?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

What is the max request interval for navigator.geolocator for each respective browser?

Chrome,
Safari,
Opera,
FireFox,
Internet Explorer?

Latest versions of course.

By interval I mean how frequent you can call the function without it returning failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that it really matters if you use [navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition#Browser_compatibility)

`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success[, error[, options]])`

and let the watch manage all the requests needed

Comment: Does this not require any error handling for browser max-calls per X time?

Comment: I'm trying to use setInterval to update the DB with user's position every X seconds and currenlty I have it on 60.000 MS, but in chrome that is too many calls and it returns false. So the user has to wait until the next function call to update the DB.

Comment: so why not let the watch do it for you? Presumably it will internally monitor limits as well as track pending requests to avoid overlap. Then 
 
you can still do your own update interval based on last known value or track time since last update in the navigator callbacks

Comment: I see, so it calls itself if the user changed its position.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this! :)

Comment: I have no experience with it to be honest ....   found it quickly by accident looking in mdn docs to see if anything there answered your question

Answer (score 0):

From MDN documentation:

> By default, getCurrentPosition() tries to answer as fast as possible with a low accuracy result. It is useful if you need a quick answer regardless of the accuracy. Devices with a GPS, for example, can take a minute or more to get a GPS fix, so less accurate data (IP location or wifi) may be returned to getCurrentPosition().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation